# How can get from file just specific data using file_get_contents and preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, file-get-contents, preg-match-all, trim

i want get data from smb.conf about sharing folder [share] and path "path =" but i want skip line with ; and // 
Thanks for answer.

Sample smb.conf

```
;[profiles]
;   comment = Users profiles
;   path = /home/samba/profiles
;   create mask = 0600
;   directory mask = 0700

[share]
   comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
   path = /storage/share
   read only = no
   guest ok = yes
   browseable = yes
   create mask = 0755
```

I've tried this but can't show path:

```
<?php 
   $smb = file('smb.conf');
   foreach ($smb as $line) { 
        $trim_line = trim ($line);
        $begin_char = substr($trim_line, 0, 1);
        $end_char = substr($trim_line, -1);
        if (($begin_char == "#") || ($begin_char == ";" || $trim_line == "[global]")) { 
        } 
        elseif (($begin_char == "[") && ($end_char == "]")) { 
            $section_name = substr ($trim_line, 1, -1); echo $section_name . '<br>'; 
        } 
   } //elseif ($trim_line != "") { // $pieces = explode("=", $trim_line , 1); } 
 ?>
```

Comment: What have you done to attempt solving this problem?

Comment: @Roman: I've edited your post; copied your comment to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
\[share\](?:.|\s)*?path\s*=\s*([^\s]*)
```

You'll find that `$matches[1]` should contain what you want.

Working example: http://regex101.com/r/kA0oZ9

PHP code:

```
$smbConf = file_get_contents("smb.conf");
preg_match('/\[share\](?:.|\s)*?path\s*=\s*([^\s]*)/im', $smbConf, $matches);
//          ^delimiter                    delimiter^ ^multiline
print_r($matches);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [share]
   comment = Ubuntu File Server Share
   path = /storage/share
    [1] => /storage/share
)
```

Comment: a try this but still didn't show <?php
$smbConf = file_get_contents('smb.conf');
preg_match('\[share\](?:.|\s)*?path\s*=\s*([^\s]*)', $smbConf, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo $matches[0];
?>

Comment: See code edit... You're not using delimiters or the multiline/case insensitive modifiers.

Comment: Now it's work thanks lot. you know some page where is explain expression? because i  absolutely don't understand expression.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can extract all these lines with `grep`/`egrep`:

```
egrep '^\[].*\]|path\s*=' smb.conf | grep -v '//'
```

Comment: there is no egrep in php